# How to implement arc menu animation in android

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I am trying to implement one arc menu similar to [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Animated-Arc-Popup-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3-Transitions/)

I have one `FloatingActionButton` as shown in this demo , on clicking on that , 4 circle buttons should pop up with slow animation. Anyone knows how to do that? Is it possible to implement it without any support libraries. I already implemented `FloatingActionButton`.

Comment: i want Floating action button like `Hangout 4.0` without using third party library.

Answer (score 0):

See this [library](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu)

Include in your layout like this

```
<com.capricorn.ArcMenu
     android:id="@+id/arc_menu_2"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     arc:fromDegrees="@dimen/menuFromDegrees"
     arc:toDegrees="@dimen/menuToDegrees"
     arc:childSize="@dimen/menuChildSize"/>
```

Comment: hey i want Floating action button like Hangout 4.0 without using third party library.

Comment: hey @sanatshukla ask new question .OP want how do that animation so library will fulfill his requirement

Comment: @Nilesh is it possible to implement this without third party libraries?

Comment: yes but you have to write your own logic , You can refer to library logic and write your own implemetation

Answer (score 0):

I have used following in by taking just necessary classes in project so no need to have un used classes you also have look

https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu

Answer (score 0):

You can use material arc menu https://github.com/saurabharora90/MaterialArcMenu

Usage

Add a dependency to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.sa90.materialarcmenu:library:1.3'

}



<com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu
    android:id="@+id/arcMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:menu_scr="@drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
    app:menu_open="arc_left">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_email"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_dialog_map"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu>
```